# Are we children or servants of HaShem?

Tags: children-parenting, commentaries, zohar, slave-serve-eved-avadim

HaShem teaches us to serve Him (Shemot 23:25), because we're His servants (Vayikra 25:42, 25:55), HaShem also teaches that we're His children (Devarim 14:1).

There is a long explanation about these verses in the Zohar (volume 6, 75-85), but I don't understand them.

So could someone please explain to me what it means to be both servants and children of HaShem (according to the Zohar)

Comment: אם כבנים רחמנו כרחם אב על בנים ואם כעבדים ...

Comment: the relationship is multifaceted and goes beyond those 2 choices http://myorthodoxlife.com/p/198/chords-for-ki-anu-amecha-a-traditional-high-holidays-song/

Comment: אבינו מלכנו. Is He our Father or our King? Yes.

Comment: our relationship with Gd is not single faceted. There are many different parables that are used to bring out a different aspect of this relationship

Comment: see this pdf (pg116) parsha toldot - http://hebrewbooks.org/15925

Comment: Can you link to the zohar (to make it easier for us)?

Comment: You specifically want the Zohar's interpretation, or is the Gemara's interpretation fine?

Comment: To which edition is the citation? Alternatively, a direct link would be more helpful. Don't know if this is the piece in Zohar you are asking about but R. de Vidas in Reishit Chochmah (here, [s.v. ותנאים](https://books.google.com/books?id=A4A_AAAAYAAJ&lpg=RA1-PT402&ots=bRGwqu04rs&dq=%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%97%D7%9B%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7%20%D7%96&pg=RA1-PT214#v=onepage&q&f=false)) explains a Zoharic piece on this same concept. Also, are you looking specifically for an explanation in English or Hebrew is fine?

Comment: @Oliver I asked this a long time ago, I think I came across it as a footnote somewhere, refering to the words Avinu Malkeinu, or the meaning of Yirah and Ahavah in relation to our role as servants and children.

Comment: Can I strongly recommend this 30min video, where R Manis Friedman will read and explain a ma'amer from the Lubavitcher Rebbe, who explains some very important details about the differences between these two relationships (turns out the Eved relationship is the same as the marriage relationship). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWdkCVrMEbc Note: the Rebbe based all of his teachings ultimately on the Zohar and the Arizal's teachings, and you can always go look up the ma'amer for more reading and references. (pretty mindblowing ma'amer, strongly recommend, R Manis is great at explaining them!)

Comment: It is extremely dangerous for someone without an exceptionally solid base to learn kabbalah - we see the confusion and misunderstandings it can lead to here. You basically say a whole bunch of kind of vague things and end off that you have no idea what it means - while it sounds deep and profound, it is very misleading.

R' Aron Lopiansky explains it very well, I reccomend listening to the Q & A in this Google drive (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YTYqq4IKdFgjG3mi77vOSdJyIQENADGa/view?usp=sharing), the question is around the 4:50 mark.

Comment: In Hayoim Haras Oilam in mussaf on Rosh Hashanah we say 'if like sons, have mercy on us like a father has mercy on his son. And if like slaves, our eyes are fixed on you...'. So it would seem that these are 2 aspects of avodah, and of our relationship to Hashem.

Answer (score 2):

I once read about fear (awe) and love as two pillars of faith.  Our relationship with the Eternal is like a love affair. A person does not transgress (maintain the prohibitions) for fear of hurting the other, for fear of disappointing the other, for fear of breaking the contract that has been drawn up together, for fear of breaking the relationship, etc.  But a person keeps his obligations (the commandments) out of unconditional love for the other, he does things not for himself or because they have to, but to show his love, because he likes to satisfy the other and wants to show that he is to give shape to his marriage vows.

So likewise fear (awe,respect) is what a slave should have, while a child should have love.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are at home in Hebrew, the fifth chabad rebbe has a 25 or so page discussion on the differences between a son and a servant (based on the arizal’s kabalistic interpretation of the Zohar like all chabad chassidut). It starts here, bottom paragraph:

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31623&st=&pgnum=319

Comment: @Eliyahu-Shmuel you wrote "We are children of God ...on the other hand we are committed to do what it says.  We see how He loves us ...because we are his sons, and on the other hand, we see that it also requires us to work it." This sounds like the part of Hashem loving is the part we are sons,  and the commitment to obey Him is the servant part. Doesn't a son also have to obey his father? Why only a servant?

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore according to the Chabad teachings based on Zohar, this is not the point. The point is that with a Father/son, it is a natural (so to speak) relationship, but with servant/Master, it is a chosen relationship. A chosen relationship is a marriage, and of course, husband and wife serve eachother devotedly as much as a Father/son. Just the character of the relationship is different. In a marriage, you give your entire self to your spouse, b'misiras nefesh. It's much deeper than Father/son, where your self is automatically bound with your Father.

Answer (score 1):

The answer (in very short):
Each one of the two - serving hashem like a son or slave - has an advantage and a disadvantage.

The advantage of serving hashem like a slave is that the reason, motive and drive for why I am seving has nothing to do with me rather only because this is what hashem wants. However the disadvantage of it is that only my actions (my external self) are serving hashem, but my intelect and feelings (my inner self) isn't, because I put my (inner) self aside.

By serving hashem like a son it is exactly the opposite, the advantage is that I understand and feel for what hashem wants (just like the relationship between a son and a father) and my entire-inner self is serving hashem. However the disadvantage is that my reason, motive and drive to serve hashem is because I understand and I feel ETC.

Based off this when it comes to serving hashem one wants both advantages, that his reason, motive and drive is like a slave to serve because hashem wants him to, and for the same reason to understand it and feel for it (for after all hashem wants our enitre-inner self to also serve him).

Comment: This is the idea of נעשה ונשמע, that the gemara says the yidden received two crowns for prioritiesing נעשה to נשמע. Which the explanation is that because they excepted עול מלכות שמים not only because of נשמע (serving hashem like a son) or not even because of נעשה alone (serving hashem like a slave), rather they received the crowns of serving hashem with נעשה prioritiesed to נשמע, as explained in the answer above.

Comment: According to this ma'amer by the Lubavitcher Rebbe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWdkCVrMEbc, the eved relationship is the same as the marriage relationship i.e. it is to do with our chosenness (Father/son is not a choice so to speak), and therefore if we choose Hashem too, then this is the highest relationship where our complete penimi is able to serve Hashem b'misiras nefesh.

Answer (score 0):

אם כבנים רחמנו כרחם אב על בנים ואם כעבדים, עינינו לך תלויות, עד שתחננו ותוציא לאור משפטנו
There is a party where we are slaves of God and we party of his sons. Because we are talking about things in a spiritual sense it does not contradict their It's not like in reality. We are children of God and He has chosen us from all the nations on the other hand we are committed to do what it says. We see how He loves us and watching over us because we are his sons, and on the other hand, we see that it also requires us to work it.

Comment: The OP was specifically looking for a discussion of the Zohar.

Answer (score 0):

According to the ma'amer of the Lubavitcher Rebbe, in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWdkCVrMEbc) as explained by R' Manis Friedman shlita (one of our best teachers of hashkafa!), which is certainly based with the entire Zohar and Arizal's teachings in mind, is that we are both.

We are more Hashem's children than our children are our own (because in Kaballah, a child originates from the Sechel of the parents, see Tanya Ch.2). This puts us in an "automatic" or "natural" (so to speak) connection with Hashem. This makes it a more superficial relationship, but is nonetheless true and important. We enjoy the natural love of a Parent and child, the sense of home and belonging, and the immense Rachamim that comes from a Father for His first born son (note, of course, all humans are Hashem's children, not just Jews).

However, Hashem also *chose us*, using His supreme Ratzon and Bechiras Chofshis, which means that Hashem Himself, b'Etzem, with His entire Self, chose to become ours ([Anochi](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.105a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) Hashem Elokecha), and we are to choose to be His too. This is the servant-Master relationship (in a marriage, each spouse should view the other as the object of their entire devotion and service, their master). This is a relationship of pure mesiras nefesh, I am for you (not Myself)*, you are for Me (not yourself). Everything I am is yours. So this *is* the marriage relationship between Hashem and His people. It is much deeper and shalem.

I just want to dwell for a moment on the importance of Ratzon (and may I recommend [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMD-i-qFmkU&list=LL) ma'amer shiur for more info). When we make a choice using our Ratzon, what are we doing? Assuming this is a true, bechiras chofshis choice, it means that we are identifying our complete self with the choice we make. This is what the deepest realest most essential and complete true me wants, all of me, and what I want is basically the highest most complete expression of who I really am. So this choice is me, and therefore I blur the line between me and Hashem and we can become truly One. (This is what Hashem wants our marriages to look like by the way!)

So the servant Master relationship is the most important one, the one that takes the hardest work, is the most fiery and passionate and complete, and will take us to our true destination and purpose. Until then, don't worry, you are also Hashem's child so even when things get intense in the more important relationship you have with Him, He will never abandon us and will always have infinite Rachamim for us.

<sup>* I believe this is what the Ramchal means when he says in Derech Hashem 1:2:1: הנה התכלית בבריאה היה להטיב מטובו ית׳‎ לזולתו i.e. that Hashem wanted to do good, from Himself (give Himself) to another. He wants to devote Himself to His kallah (Yisrael), that's why He created the world, and of course, our job is to complete that relationship and devote our entire selves to Him! I don't have a source that this is what the Ramchal means himself, but it is a concept in chassidus that would fit well with those words.</sup>